# I get error each time i try to enable jekyll server on CMD

Tags: github, jekyll

```
C:\JekyllBlog>jekyll server --watch
Configuration file: C:/JekyllBlog/_config.yml
       Deprecation: You appear to have pagination turned on, but you haven't inc
luded the `jekyll-paginate` gem. Ensure you have `gems: [jekyll-paginate]` in yo
ur configuration file.
            Source: C:/JekyllBlog
       Destination: C:/JekyllBlog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
  Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have pygments or one of its d
ependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll ne
ed to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such f
ile -- pygments' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at http
://jekyllrb.com/help/!
  Liquid Exception: pygments in C:/JekyllBlog/_posts/2014-11-28-markdown-and-htm
l.md
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    pygments
```

I'm not a prgrammer but each time i enable jekyll server. This is what it comes on CMD on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

> Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have pygments

So a `gem install pygments` can do the trick.